# Flask request waiting for asynchronous background job

Tags: python, api, flask

I have an HTTP API using Flask and in one particular operation clients use it to retrieve information obtained from a 3rd party API. The retrieval is done with a celery task. Usually, my approach would be to accept the client request for that information and return a `303 See Other` response with an URI that can be polled for the response as the background job is finished.

However, some clients require the operation to be done in a single request. They don't want to poll or follow redirects, which means I have to run the background job synchronously, hold on to the connection until it's finished, and return the result in the same response. I'm aware of Flask streaming, but how to do such long-pooling with Flask?

Comment: To get this to work, just do not return the response back to the client until the job is done. But, make sure to be running inside of a gevent wsgi container so that you do not end up exhausting your server's resources. For dev purposes run the server with the `threaded=True`.

Comment: The problem is how to prevent the client from timing out during that.

Comment: You're really kind of at the mercy of the client. Depending on the client it might be good to push some kind of identifier so that they can get the response if they do happen to close the connection for whatever reason in the middle of the request.

Answer (score 1):

Tornado would do the trick.
Flask is not designed for asynchronization. A Flask instance processes one request at a time in one thread. Therefore, when you hold the connection, it will not proceed to next request.

Comment: That's not a problem.